# Receiving output 0 when using Rcpp's cppFunction() in R

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am using Rcpp to speed up a double `for` loop in R. I've implemented the *C++* code as follows; however, regardless of the kind of input -- e.g. any kind of vectors or numbers -- I put in the function, I end up always receiving 0 as the result.

Where I did wrong in my code?

```
#include<Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double likelihood(NumericVector pA, NumericVector pB,
                  NumericVector pA_bin, NumericVector pB_bin,
                  double x_A, double x_B, double t_l)
{
  int nrow = pA.size();
  int ncol = pB.size();
  int nvec = nrow*(nrow-1)/2;
  int kk = 0;
  NumericVector p_l_nu_vec(nvec);
  //define 4 double variables to store coordinates of 4 vertices of each element
  double x1 = 0;
  double x2 = 0;
  double y1 = 0;
  double y2 = 0;
  //define 4 variables to store likelihood function values at 4 vertices
  double f1 = 0;   //point 1, bottom-left, (x1,y1)
  double f2 = 0;   //point 2, bottom-right, (x2,y1)
  double f3 = 0;   //point 3, top-right, (x2,y2)
  double f4 = 0;   //point 4, top-left, (x1,y2)


  for (int j=0;j<ncol;++j){
    for (int i=0;i<nrow;++i){
      if (i>j){
        // trapzoid rule, taking average of 4 vertices of the triangular 
        x1 = pA_bin[i];    //x value of left, point 1,4
        x2 = pA_bin[i+1];  //x value of right, point 2,3
        y1 = pB_bin[j];    //y value of bottom, point 1,2 
        y2 = pB_bin[j+1];  //y value of top, point 3,4
        f1 = pow(1-x1,t_l-x_A)*pow(x1-y1,x_A-x_B)*pow(y1,x_B);
        f2 = pow(1-x2,t_l-x_A)*pow(x2-y1,x_A-x_B)*pow(y1,x_B);
        f3 = pow(1-x2,t_l-x_A)*pow(x2-y2,x_A-x_B)*pow(y2,x_B);
        f4 = pow(1-x1,t_l-x_A)*pow(x1-y2,x_A-x_B)*pow(y2,x_B);
        //take the average of 4 vertices
        p_l_nu_vec[kk] = 1/4*(f1+f2+f3+f4);
        kk = kk+1;
      }
    }
  }

  //return p_l_nu_vec;
  return kk;
}
```

Sample call in *R*:

```
p_l_nu_vec_trapzoid = likelihood(pA,pB,pA_bin,pB_bin,x_A,x_B,t_l)
```

Expected results should output some real numbers instead of being 0 all the time. For example, in this case, output kk records the number of iterations.

Comment: It's possible kk is 0 if pA.size() and pB.size() are 0. Are you sure the data is getting into the cppFunction correctly. Maybe start with a simpler case like return pA.size() or return pB.size()? Check the data before even calling the function. I am not sure how you else you can debug RCPP.

Comment: @Daniel Even if they are 1 the if condition will never be true. OP needs to show some input data.

Comment: A simple counterexample to your claim that "0 always is the result": try `likelihood(1:2, 1:2, 1:3, 1:3, 1, 2, 3)`. After compiling the exact function you provided, that call gave a result of `1` for me. As @Roland says, we need to see what the input data looks like that is giving you problems to have any hope of pointing you toward your issue.

Comment: Sorry for the late update. My input data is like: pA_bin = seq(0,0.1,1e-4); pB_bin = seq(0,0.1,1e-4); pA = diff(pA_bin)/2+pA_bin[-length(pA_bin)];  pB = diff(pB_bin)/2+pB_bin[-length(pB_bin)]

Comment: So what I am doing now is to find  intervals within pA_bin(pB_bin)  for each element of pA(pB).

Comment: I might find the probelm. In the code: p_l_nu_vec[kk] = 1/4*(f1+f2+f3+f4);  I should use 0.25 instead of 1/4, the later one will give me a vector of 0.  Thank you all for your help!

Comment: @Kevin `1.0/4.0` should also work.